# Create a javascript for loop instead of all my if´s

Tags: javascript

How can i make a simple for loop for my if cases?
This is taking to much space.. and i'm not good at for loops...
Please help me..
I´ll try...

```
for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
if(result[i] === null){
```

**CODE**

```
if(null === result.RosaAvformning.jan){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"jan":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.feb){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"feb":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.mar){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"mar":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.apr){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"apr":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.maj){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"maj":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.jun){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"jun":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.jul){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"jul":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.aug){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"aug":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.sep){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"sep":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.okt){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"okt":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.nov){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"nov":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.dec){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"dec":"0"}
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

```
var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Maj","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dec"];

    months.forEach(function (m){
        if (result.RosaAvformning[m] === null) {
            result.RosaAvformning = {};
            result.RosaAvformning[m] = 0;
        }
    });

    months.forEach(function (m){
        if (result.BlåAvformning[m] === null) {
            result.BlåAvformning = {};
            result.BlåAvformning[m] = 0;
        }
    });

    console.log(result.RosaAvformning.mar);
```

Jan, and feb is filled, but not the rest.
mar will give me "undefined" not "0" as i'd like..

Comment: Can your result array contain more than 12 values?

Comment: If jan and feb are both `null` `result` will be overwritten. Will that ever be the case?

Comment: By no means to be rude, but the provided code doesn't make sense. Are you sure the example in the post is the same as your real code? Notice also, that retrieving the value of a non-existing property doesn't return `null` by default, `undefined` is returned instead.

Comment: You can not use loop until you make your months(result.RosaAvformning.jan) iterable. In other words let's say that you are using loop to find out value of month if it is null or not but how you will move from jan to fab since it is not iterable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the provided code makes a lot of sense, it will overwrite the result again and again. However, here's how to convert it to loops:

Create a array with all keys you want to test. Then loop over those keys and for each see if it is `null` and if yes, assign zero:

```
function oldTest(result) {
  if(null === result.RosaAvformning.jan){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"jan":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.feb){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"feb":"0"}
            };
        }
        if(null === result.RosaAvformning.mar){
            result = {
                "RosaAvformning" : {"mar":"0"}
            };
        }
  return result;
}


function test (result) {
    var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar"];

    months.forEach(function (m){
      if (null === result.RosaAvformning[m]) {
        result.RosaAvformning = {};
        result.RosaAvformning[m] = 0;
        return result;
      }
    });
    return result;
}

// init test data
var result = {};
result.RosaAvformning = {  
  "jan" : null,
  "feb" : null,
  "mar" : null
};

// test no months set
console.log ("Old Test 1", test(result));
console.log ("new Test 1", oldTest(result));

// set one month
result.RosaAvformning = {
  "jan" : 1,
  "feb" : 1,
  "mar" : null
};

// test one months set
console.log ("Old Test 2", test(result));
console.log ("new Test 2", oldTest(result));
```

I prepared a small JSBin (with only three months due to lazyness) and two tests both your code (`oldTest()`) and mine (`test()`): https://jsbin.com/vicinuwuyi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, the result is "undefined" not "null" as i thougth. Can i know do it like this: `if (result.RosaAvformning[m] === "undefined") {` ??

Comment: `if (result.RosaAvformning[m] === undefined) {` . However, unless you have a specific reason do discern between null and undefined, `if (result.RosaAvformning[m] == null) {` will also do.

Comment: If i use: `if (result.RosaAvformning[m] === null) {` <br> `console.log(result.RosaAvformning.mar);` will give "undefined" in colsole... i'd like it to be "0"

Comment: Please look at the JSBin I gave you, it prints "0" for march.

Comment: Just use `if (result.RosaAvformning[m] == null) {`

Comment: Your code works because you set `jan = null`. I cannot do that. Either i have  result.RosaAvformning.Jan or it doesn't exists. So, i must check if it exists.. if i check for null it won't work, because it don´t even exists..

Comment: check Temuu's comment above. I know you solved it by setting null. But i cannot do that.

Comment: I just copied from your code, you explicitly test against null: `if (null === result.RosaAvformning.jan`

Comment: Here's code that does not set months to null: https://jsbin.com/nebukiduje/edit?js,console - but I still don't think that's what you intend to do.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. I didn't know that null did not work for undefined.

Comment: Here is what I believe you are trying to achieve: set every undefined month to zero: https://jsbin.com/nadatewequ/1/edit?js,console - look at "new Test 1"

Comment: Thank you. I used it like this:  `months.forEach(function (m){
            if (! result.RosaAvformning[m]) {
                result.RosaAvformning[m] = {};
                result.RosaAvformning[m] = 0;
            }
        });`

Answer (score -1):

I'm *assuming* the intention is to replace all null month properties with zeros. Thats **not** what the code in question does - that replaces the whole which result from last matched if...

---

Declare months with something like

```
var months = ["jan", "feb", ...
```

and loop over them with

```
var i, len, month;
for (i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; i++) {
   month = months[i];   
   if (null === result.RosaAvformning[month]){ // this null === will NOT match undefined properties!!!
      result.RosaAvformning[month] = "0";
   }
}
```

If you're sure that `month` is a declared `null` property of `result.RosaAvformning` then you can loop over that with

```
for (key in someObject) {
    if ( someObject.hasOwnProperty(key) ) { // ignore class fields
       // access someObject[key])
    }
}
```

but it will fail you have `undefined` properties not `null` properties - and can match non-month properties as well...

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of your code you just want to test for what month they have done.

To condense the if statements into a for loop it would be something like this

```
var arrayList = [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec];
var result;

for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    result = "RosaAvformning : {i : 0}";
}
```

Or something along those lines, I believe you are using a user input so you'd need to add that into the mix, I would need to see it to integrate it :)